# Htmlspecialchars ENT_NOQUOTES not working?

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I'm trying to output the name of a project i.e. "David's Project" in a form, if a user does not correctly input all data in the form, to save the user having to input the name again.

If I var_dump $name I see David's project. But if I echo $name I see David"&#39" Project. I realise that ' (single quote) becomes "&#039"; but I have tried using ENT_NOQUOTES and ENT_COMPAT to avoid encoding the single quote but neither works.

```
$name = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name0', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

<form method="post" class="form" />
Title: <input type="text" name="name0" value="<?php echo 
htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_NOQUOTES); ?>">
```

Am I doing something wrong or should the ENT_NOQUOTES work? I tried using str_replace to replace with ' with an \' but this didn't work either.

The only way round this I have found is to use this:

```
htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_NOQUOTES));
```

Is that acceptable?

Sorry I realise this is probably a really stupid question but I just can't get my head around it.

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: How are you viewing the text value? Inspect Element is **not** the same as viewing the page's source code; and seeing it rendered in the web browser is also different. You are probably getting confused with how browsers tend to try and "fix" stuff for you so that you never even know it's an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Zeus. I'm viewing both in the browser. But it is also inserting the encoded single quote into the database.

Comment: Oh dear... **NEVER** escape data before putting it in the database, always save data as-is because you never know where that data will need to be displayed. Only escape data when outputting to a display medium such as a web browser, Android app, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accept a simple answer if it solves your problem BUT you should really understand that what you have delved into is a much larger issue you or someone has created for you.

1. Databases should not contain HTML encoded characters unless they are specifically meant for storing HTML. I highly doubt this is the case as it very rarely is.
2. Someone is inserting HTML into your database (html encoding data on insert). This means if you ever want to use a mobile app that is not HTML based, or a command line, or anything at all that might use the data and isn't HTML based, you are going to run into a weird problem where the HTML encoded characters have to be removed on output. This is typically kind of the backwards way to do it and can often cause issues.
3. You rarely need to "sanitize" your inputs. If anything, you should reject input that is not allowed OR simply escape it in the proper way while inserting it into the database. Sanitizing is only a thing in very special circumstances, which you don't appear to have right now. You're simply inputting and outputting text.
4. You should pretty much never *change* users input

My suggestion, if possible, is to fix your INSERT code first so it isn't html encoding data. This html encoding should happen when you output the data TO AN HTML FORMAT. You would use `htmlspecialchars()` to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply Joe. I apprecaite it. I'm trying to take it all in. Are you saying that the FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING is encoding the single quote and causing the problem?

Comment: Sanitize is going to either strip or encode html tags. You do NOT want to use that while putting it into a database. This could potentially be used when display it though. So yes, that is definitely part of the problem. The only thing you should really be *escaping* on input is SQL injection attempts (which you should be using a proper library like PDO library and parameterized queries)

Comment: I thought Sanitize string was helping stop SQL injection. I am obviously getting my wires crossed and need to read up a bit more. I'm not really sure the various ways SQL injection could occur, so was going for belt and braces approach.

I am also using Prepared statements with placeholders whilst dealing with the SQL database insertion. I thought I had to do both. So would that be enough in this case?

Comment: @MartinP13 It's a common problem/misunderstanding. For sql injection, you should simply use prepared statements. For XSS (cross site scripting) it's a bit more complicated, but simply put, you need to properly encode your output. The method of doing so changes depending specifically on what you're outputting and where to. Check OWASP for a in depth explanation on XSS